# Does voltage increase or decrease as a function of distance?

Tags: electric-circuits

Voltage can be written as $$V = Ed$$ or $$V = \frac{kq}{r}$$ So is voltage inversely or directly proportional to the distance?

Comment: Assuming $d$ is distance, $V$ is proportional to distance in this formula but inversely proportional to radius in the second formula. Maybe you can give a concrete example where these formulas are used (or, if they have a name, how they are called). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation, $V=Ed$, assumes a uniform (constant) field $E$ over the distance $d$. An example is the voltage between the plates of a parallel plate capacitor separated by the distance $d$ due to sheets of charge.

The second equation, V=kq/r, is based on the electric field due to a point charge $q$ which varies as the inverse square of the distance from the point charge per coulombs law.

So the answer to your question is you are comparing apples and oranges.

Hope this helps.